# Moving user perspective in Blender with Python

Tags: python, 3d-view

How can I move the user perspective in Blender with Python? I did some research, but I wasn't able, to find anything.

For clarification: I want to move the user camera in the 3D view. I want to achieve the same effect as the user pressing his middle mouse button and moving the mouse.

Comment: Are you asking how to zoom the camera when looking through it?

Comment: @iKlsR I want do the same, as if i would move around with my mouse. So, not only zooming...

Comment: You could try [`bpy.ops.view3d.move`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.view3d.html?highlight=view%20bpy#bpy.ops.view3d.move) and [`rotate`](http://www.blender.org/documentation/blender_python_api_2_69_1/bpy.ops.view3d.html?highlight=view%20bpy#bpy.ops.view3d.rotate)

Comment: @gandalf3 `bpy.ops.view3d.move` is not intended to be used from python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `bpy.ops.view3d.view_pan()` to do the same as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad #</kbd>, e.g.:

```
for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
        override = {'area': area, 'region': area.regions[-1]}
        bpy.ops.view3d.view_pan(override, type='PANRIGHT')
```

The amount of the panning can't be controlled.

If you manipulate the `view_matrix` (or `view_location` etc.) directly, there's a lot more control. But you will have to calculate the proper matrices and vectors, and if something went wrong, you may end up with strange view or navigation reaction:

```
r3d = C.screen.areas[2].spaces[0].region_3d # region_3d of 3D View
r3d.view_matrix.col[3][1:4] # translation part of the view matrix
```

Have a look at the FPS Fly addon to see what can be done and how:
http://www.ewocprojects.be/fpsfly.html

AFAIK viewport navigation is a bit weird after use, as the addon might manipulate the wrong property to fly around. The [C-implementation](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User%3aDfelinto/Ideas#FPS_Navigation) will be different.

Comment: See [View Navigation: Walk and Fly modes](https://github.com/dfelinto/blender-git/pull/1). Soon. :)